# How instagram app knows my device location without internet, gps, sim card

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, location, instagram

If your answer is `TimeZone,TelephonyManager,Locale,ip adress/http request` please elaborate properly.

**1.** `Uninstall instagram app` on your device then `install it again`. Before opening instagram app `turn off your internet` for more clarity you can `turn on airplane mode/aeroplane mode/flight` mode. Now open instagram app. `Click on create account`. Now you can see your country name and code in phone number edit box. **From this we concluded that instagram doesn't use ip adress/http request as there is no internet available.**

**2.** No need to explain about `TimeZone,TelephonyManager,Locale`. As we know these are not working at certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you gave it location permission, it doesn't need any of that.  It doesn't need a working internet connection, it can get cellular location just by pining what towers are nearby, which doesn't need a working SIM, it just needs to be able to detect a signal.  Same for wifi-  you don't need to be on a wifi network, you just need to be able to detect wifi signals.

Of course for something as vague as country name and code there's a dozen possible answers.  Locale is the most likely-  if your language is set to en_us, it uses 1 and USA.  If its fr_fr, it uses the french country code.  Etc.

Comment: Nope that's why I mentioned clean uninstall and install and after clean install First I turned on flight mode and my gps was off then after instagram can detect my country code

Comment: FLight mode isn't going to matter unless it was on from the moment your phone booted-  it will have the data from before it was turned on, unless you've had it off for hours..  And country code can be guessed just from locale, as I mentioned.

Comment: Country code always return US, Maximum device default is US and less number of user update that to their countries